# Model over DVR for smooth projective curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, deformation-theory, curves-and-surfaces, valuation-theory

Let $C$ be a smooth, projective, geometrically irreducible curve of genus at least $2$ over a complete discrete valued field $F$ of characteristic zero (not necessarily algebraically closed). Let $R$ be the ring of integers of $F$. Assume that the residue field of $R$ is algebraically closed. Does there exist a model of $C$ over $R$ such that the special fiber is irreducible with at worst nodal singularities?

I know that by Deligne-Mumford, there always exists a semi-stable model, which only guarentees a reducible curve with at worst nodal singularities, but I am asking if we can do better?

Comment: No. If you have a model where the special fiber is stable and reducible (for instance, the union of 2 smooth curves meeting transversally, both of genus $>0$), you cannot find a semi-stable model with an irreducible fiber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lemma 1.12 in the Deligne-Mumford paper, the answer is no.  Any isomorphism of generic fibers extends uniquely to an isomorphism over $R$.  This is one way of saying that the stack $\mathcal{M}_g$ of genus $g$ stable curves is proper.

Comment: note that the uniqueness requires stability, which includes a condition on not having certain irreducible components. However I guess having one irreducible component always implies this